# Why does the solution of this Laplace Equation need to be of the form $\sum_{n\geq 1} \sin{nx} [A_n \sinh{(ny)} + B_n \sinh{(n(y- \pi))}]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ solve the Laplace equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions:

$$\Delta u = 0  \\u(x,0)=\sin x \\u(x,\pi)=\sin x + 1/2 \sin(2x) \\ u(0,y) = u(\pi,y )=0$$ with $0 \leq x,y \leq \pi$

We want to find the explicit formula for $u$.
We look for a solution of the form $$u(x,y)= \sum_{n\geq 1} \sin{nx} [A_n \sinh{(ny)} + B_n \sinh{(n(y- \pi))}]$$

(...)

---

May I ask you why the solution needs to be like $\sum_{n\geq 1} \sin{nx} [A_n \sinh{(ny)} + B_n \sinh{(n(y- \pi))}]$ ?

Comment: This came from separation of variables. The $\sin (nx)$ terms pop up because of the requirement that the solutions vanish at $x=0,\pi$. These are eigenfunctions of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with vanishing endpoint conditions. The solutions in $y$ are hyperbolic. They are just conveniently dividing these into sums of 2 functions, one that vanishes at $y=0$ and the other that vanishes at $y=\pi$. That simplifies the process of imposing conditions at $y=0$ and $y=\pi$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Do you know any website where I could see how it is derived ? Thanks for your help by the way